# Java SWT exception : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" : Menu is not a POP_UP

Tags: java, exception, swt

I try to create a Menu using the SWT object "Menu".
Lines of codes are rather simple :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    createShell();
}


private static void createShell() {

    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);

    Menu menu = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
    shell.setMenu(menu);

    shell.open();

    while (! shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();

}
```

At runtime, I get the following exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Menu is not a POP_UP
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setMenu(Unknown Source)
at labo.Laboratory.createShell(Laboratory.java:25)
at labo.Laboratory.main(Laboratory.java:15)
```

the swt code that seems to to be involved is the one from the "setMenu" method :

```
public void setMenu (Menu menu) {
checkWidget ();
if (menu != null) {
    if (menu.isDisposed()) error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    if ((menu.style & SWT.POP_UP) == 0) {
        error (SWT.ERROR_MENU_NOT_POP_UP);
    }
    if (menu.parent != menuShell ()) {
        error (SWT.ERROR_INVALID_PARENT);
    }
}
this.menu = menu;
```

}

Obvisously I go to the following line of code :

```
if ((menu.style & SWT.POP_UP) == 0) {
    error (SWT.ERROR_MENU_NOT_POP_UP);
}
```

But I cannot understand why. The code I try to execute is given as a valid example everywhere, but it does not work for me.

I am using eclipse IDE, with a Java 8 JRE.
SWT library is the one provided by eclipse neon. The OS I am using is Windows 7.

I have reproduced this error with other computers and configurations, but curiously it seems that nobody else is facing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setMenu` method sets the pop-up menu for any control. The menu style for this **must** be `SWT.POP_UP`.

You are probably looking for the `setMenuBar` method of `Shell` which sets to menu bar at the top of the window (top of the screen on macOS). This requires the menu style to be `SWT.BAR`.

Comment: That's it. I picked the setMenu method instead of the setMenuBar.

Comment: It was a very silly mistake of mine. many thanks for your help :-)